# UITableViewCell - How to hide the editing mode of deleting tableview row

Tags: ios, uitableview

I added **canEditRowAtIndexPath** in TableView so that TableViewRow can be deleted if required.

It shows all the time the minus sign in front of the TableViewRow which looks odd.

I want to hide it somehow.

It should be only shown when user swipes the row to delete it.

```
 - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
[self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
return YES;
}

 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

    PFUser *userToDelete = [self.friends objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"Deleting User: %@", userToDelete.username);
    [self.friendsRelation removeObject:userToDelete];
    [[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];

    [self.friends removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, 1);
    NSIndexSet *sectionToReload = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:range];
    [tableView reloadSections:sectionToReload withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
 }


- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = editing;
[super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
 }
```

How can i hide this minus sign which is showing in front of the tableview row all the time.

I want when user swipes the tableview row only then it should appear both minus sign and delete row sign.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your table is in editing mode then the - will show.  Swipe to delete is available when the table isn't in editing mode and no - will be shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use this method to have a swipe delete option in you app:-
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

Comment out the -canEditRowAtIndexPath method and see the result for yourself.